# checkbox should be checked before clicking delete commandbutton... how to do in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

```
 <h:form>
        <rich:dataTable value="#{classBean.classList}" var="class"
                id="classTable" style="width: 90%" rows="10">    
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="class list" style="float: left"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <rich:column style="width: 35px">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
            value="#{classBean.selected[class.name]}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                   class name
             </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{class.name}" />
        </rich:column>  
        <f:facet name="footer">
           <a4j:commandButton value="add" action="#{classBean.add}" />
           <a4j:commandButton value="delete" action="#{classBean.delete}" />
         </f:facet>
        <rich:dataTable>
     <h:form>
```

I have to validate such as the user should select at least one checkbox before clicking delete command button.

If I use validator it will check only checked or uncheked.... I need to check the checkbox when delete commandButton clicked

Comment: You should use a validator.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your bean

```
private boolean checked;

public boolean isChecked() 
{

    if(selected.values().contains(true))
        checked=true;
    else
        checked=false;


    return checked;
}
```

use a popup panel to display error message and  set the rendered attribute to #{bean.checked}

Comment: Is that extra property and the whole if-else on a boolean assignment really necessary? Why not just put this oneliner `return selected.values().contains(true);`?

Comment: @BalusC You mean that there is no need of a new property "checked"? If so ,then how it is accessible without using bean Id from a jsf page

Comment: Just the same way. You don't need to remove `isChecked()` method.